# How should I care for newly planted saplings on a slope?

Tags: trees, tree-care, planting, technique

Me and couple of my mates are trying to plant few trees on a hill slope before the wet season (monsoon) sets in India (early June).

The hill has been devoid of trees due to excessive felling in last few decades. 
Should I take specific care so that most of the saplings survive and grow into large trees?

Comment: How steep is the hill? What kind of trees?

Comment: dont know the gradiant, but its a steep hill. it would increase ones heart rate while climbing. I am thinking of planting trees which are native to Pune region. The trees which can attract birds.

Answer (score 8):

ViSu, You reminded me of the same experience I and my friends had before. In our college days, we planted a number of saplings on a barren land\hill slope.

As you are going to plant in a hilly area (which could be really hot these days), **you need to take care of few things:**

1. Ensure your saplings are not very small. (Small plants can be eaten by local animals)
2. You have to regularly water them for at least a month. (We planted many saplings, but we didn't water them, and at last all plants died. We had to plant them again.)
3. If possible, give them fertilizer (dried manure is also fine)
4. (Only if required) use a pesticide to keep insects under control (diluted neem oil spray).
5. If possible, guard the saplings physically, such as with mesh protectors or vinyl tree guards.

Comment: Thanks JacZjill. The large saplings is a good idea. I was thinking of planting young saplings. but larger one will work better. I plan to plan them by end of May or early june when the first rains of the season arrive so that they get enough water for next 3-4 months during the wet season. .

Comment: Yes, that's best idea!